# Export variable from app.py to another python file

Tags: python, flask

I created a Flask app with SQLAlchemy.
I initialised the database in `app.py` but I want to use it in another file: `otherfile.py`.

**app.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///my_database'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
print("TEST")
```

**otherfile.py**

```
from app import db
print(db)
```

But I get the error.

> > ImportError: cannot import name 'db'

Basically, I am doing this because I do not want to write the SQLAlchemy logic in `app.py` but I want to keep it in another file.

**In addition**, I just want the variable `db` to be exported. I do not want that when I run `otherfile.py`, this runs also `print("TEST")` which is in `app.py`

I looked at these answer with little luck:

[How to share the global app object in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284858/how-to-share-the-global-app-object-in-flask)

[Split Python Flask app into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231359/split-python-flask-app-into-multiple-files)

[How to divide flask app into multiple py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994325/how-to-divide-flask-app-into-multiple-py-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQLAlchemy` class doesn't need to receive the `app` param on its initialization. So what you can do is create the `db` object in your `otherfile.py` and import it in `app.py`, where you can pass it the `app` object with `SQLAlchemy.init_app()`.

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from otherfile import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///my_database'

db.init_app(app)
```

**otherfile.py**

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I now connect in `otherfile.py` my sqlite database? Or is it already connected since I wrote in app.py `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///my_database)`?

Comment: @Prova12 It will connect once that it is needed using the credentials that you set in app.config